# Is it possible to break up this statement without introducing ambiguity?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I have the following grammar which works fine:

```
selectStatement
    : simpleSelectStatement (setOperand selectStatement)?;
```

However, I would like to break up the `selectStatement` so it tells us at the top level whether it contains a set operation at all. For example:

```
selectStatement
    : simpleSelectStatement | setOperation
    ;

setOperation
    : simpleSelectStatement (setOperand selectStatement)
    ;
```

Unfortunately, to parse this unambiguously, it has to examine the entire `SELECT` statement to see if there is a `UNION` there to see which rule to delegate to. For example, with the below taking 24 lookaheads to figure out what type of statement it is!

[image]

Is there a way to resolve this, or is the only way basically "Put it back into one root statement-type" (as the `UNION` usually comes 'so late in the statement' that delegating the statement type could almost take an entire parse itself). Here is a full working grammar to test with:

```
grammar DBParser;
options { caseInsensitive=true; }

root
    : selectStatement SEMI? EOF
    ;

selectStatement
    : simpleSelectStatement | setOperation
    ;

setOperation
    : simpleSelectStatement (setOperand selectStatement)
    ;

simpleSelectStatement:
    ( selectClause | OPEN_PAREN selectStatement CLOSE_PAREN)
    ;

selectClause
    : SELECT selectItem (COMMA selectItem)*
    ;
selectItem
    : NUMBER ( FROM IDENTIFIER )?
    ;

setOperand
    : UNION ALL?|EXCLUDE|INTERSECT
    ;

SELECT              :           'SELECT';                   // SELECT *...
LIMIT               :           'LIMIT';                    // ORDER BY x LIMIT 20
ALL                 :           'ALL';                      // SELECT ALL vs. SELECT DISTINCT; WHERE ALL (...); UNION ALL...
UNION               :           'UNION';                    // Set operation
FROM                :           'FROM';                    // Set operation
AS                  :           'AS';                      // Set operation
WITH                :           'WITH';                    // Set operation

SEMI                :           ';';                        // Statement terminator
OPEN_PAREN          :           '(';                        // Function calls, object declarations
CLOSE_PAREN         :           ')';
COMMA         :           ',';

NUMBER
     : [0-9]+
    ;
IDENTIFIER
    : [A-Z_] [A-Z_0-9]*
    ;
WHITESPACE
    : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
    ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just try labelled alternatives?

```
grammar DBParser;
options { caseInsensitive=true; }

root
    : selectStatement SEMI? EOF
    ;

selectStatement
    : SELECT selectItem (COMMA selectItem)* # simpleSelect
    | OPEN_PAREN selectStatement CLOSE_PAREN # parenSelect
    | selectStatement setOperand selectStatement # setOperation
    ;

//setOperation
//    : simpleSelectStatement setOperand selectStatement # set
//    ;

//simpleSelectStatement:
//     selectClause
//     | OPEN_PAREN selectStatement CLOSE_PAREN
//    ;

//selectClause
//    : SELECT selectItem (COMMA selectItem)*
//    ;
selectItem
    : NUMBER ( FROM IDENTIFIER )?
    ;

setOperand
    : UNION ALL?|EXCLUDE|INTERSECT
    ;

SELECT              :           'SELECT';                   // SELECT *...
LIMIT               :           'LIMIT';                    // ORDER BY x LIMIT 20
ALL                 :           'ALL';                      // SELECT ALL vs. SELECT DISTINCT; WHERE ALL (...); UNION ALL...
UNION               :           'UNION';                    // Set operation
FROM                :           'FROM';                    // Set operation
AS                  :           'AS';                      // Set operation
WITH                :           'WITH';                    // Set operation

SEMI                :           ';';                        // Statement terminator
OPEN_PAREN          :           '(';                        // Function calls, object declarations
CLOSE_PAREN         :           ')';
COMMA         :           ',';

NUMBER
     : [0-9]+
    ;
IDENTIFIER
    : [A-Z_] [A-Z_0-9]*
    ;
WHITESPACE
    : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
    ;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you please explain a bit about what the `labelled alternatives` do? I can't seem to find much information on that.

Comment: By labeling your alternatives, you get a separate context class for each alternative, like you would for an independent rule, but you also get the immediate left-recursion and precedence of ANTLR alternatives in a single rule.  Because you get separate Context classes, you’ll also have listener methods that will be specific to the alternative.

Comment: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#alternative-labels

Comment: thanks. Is that a sort of work-around for some of the limitations in the left-recursion while working for antlr?

Comment: I wouldn’t consider it a “work-around”.   Allowing direct left-recursion is a feature of ANTLR4 as it significantly simplifies a lot of grammars.  I’m sure if there hadn’t been issues with indirect left-recursion, they’d have allowed for it as well.  Without that feature you have to “work around” left recursion by factoring it out with techniques to remove left-recursion.